# Error connected with values in R - IMDB API

Tags: r, api

Currently I'm writing IMDB movie data base API in RStudio. I have already written code which download movies but after some time there is error about value in one column, despite it looks just like the previous one. There is an error:

Error: Column `Ratings` must be length 1, not 0

```html
library(tidyverse)

library(imdbapi)

movies <- read.csv("movie_titles.csv", header = F)
names(movies) <- c("no", "year", "name")

movies_10 <- movies %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(year=as.numeric(year)) %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1994:2004))

omdb_api_key(force = T) #708d1c87

movies_imdb <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:100000){
  m <- find_by_title(title = movies_10$name[i], year_of_release = movies_10$year[i], api_key = omdb_api_key())
  if(nrow(m) > 0){
    movies_imdb <- union_all(movies_imdb, m)
  
  }
    m <- find_by_title(title = movies_10$name[i], year_of_release = movies_10$year[i], api_key = omdb_api_key())

  }
```

I have already tried deleting this column because i do not need this one. I have also heard about trycatch

Comment: Problem solved :)